# Blazor | How to jump from parent component to child component with a Button

Tags: javascript, blazor

I have two Razor Pages.The Parent Page needs to pass parameters to the child page.And it has an event which calls the event from the child page.
Now I want to render the whole page with the child page, how to implement?
PS : In fact,They are two pages.Cause i need to pass parameters between the two page,i see them as parent and child component.

main code in Parent Page

```
<MatButton Raised="true" OnClick="GeneratePdf">GeneratePdf</MatButton>
<table >
            <tr >
                <td width="300">描述 <br> Description </td>
                <td width="500">标准选项  <br> Standard Option</td>
                <td width="400">备注  <br> Comments</td>
            </tr>
            ……
</table>
<ABSReporting @ref="child" ABSTI="@ABSTI" ABSTI_HU="@ABSTI.HU"/>  //The child page
@code
{
ABSReporting child;
private void GeneratePdf()
    {
        child.GeneratePdf();
    }
}
```

main code in Child page（The child page name is ABSReporting.razor）

```
<div @ref=RenderContent> 
     <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="500" class="text-center">
                    ABS Technical Information
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: #CCFFFF" width="400" class="text-center">
                    V6.0
                </td>
            </tr>
            ……
        </table>
</div>
@code
{
 [Parameter]
    public ABSTI ABSTI { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public ABSTI_HU ABSTI_HU { get; set; }

    ElementReference RenderContent;
    public async void GeneratePdf()
    {
        string html = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("BlazorUniversity.innerHTML", RenderContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> They are two pages

They are not. Even if ABSReporting is a routable component (containing the @page directive with a route template: `@page "/ABSReporting"`, the ABSReporting component is used as the child component of the Parent Page.

Change this:

```
private void GeneratePdf()
{
    child.GeneratePdf();
}
```

To

```
private async Task GeneratePdf()
{
    await child.GeneratePdf();
}
```

And

```
public async void GeneratePdf()
{
    string html = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string> 
    ("BlazorUniversity.innerHTML", RenderContent);
}
```

To

```
public async Task GeneratePdf()
{
    string html = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string> 
    ("BlazorUniversity.innerHTML", RenderContent);

    InvokeAsync(() => {StateHasChanged();});
}
```

What is `BlazorUniversity.innerHTML` ? According to Blazor conventions `BlazorUniversity` is a namespace defined on the window object, and `innerHTML` is a JS function that has a single parameter (ElementReference)...
Is that the case ?

Comment: Yes, it's a JS function which used to converte razor page to html string,cause i want to use an interface which can be  used to convert html pags to pdf.

Comment: I tried your advice.they're still one page. What i want to implement is that use the value transferred by the parent component, while the child component can be a single page. Thank you so much for your kindness

Comment: Oh,i have solved the problem,what i need to do is just add a

Comment: @Kiki, would you please finish your comment... What was the issue and how did you solve it?

Comment: what I want to achieve is that if I click the Button in the Parent page, it will jump to the child page.Will it be Okey? What i do now is just add a judge statement and it cant sovle the fundamental problem. Child page as follows.

Comment: ```
@if (show)
{
    <div>...</div>
}
@code
{
    bool show = false;
    public async Task GeneratePdf()
    {
        show = true;
        StringBuilder ABS_string = new StringBuilder();
        string html_1 = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("BlazorUniversity.outerHTML", ABSTitle);
        string html_2 = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("BlazorUniversity.outerHTML", ABSHU);
        ABS_string.Append(html_1);
        ABS_string.Append(html_2);
        string html = ABS_string.ToString();
        show = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

child page Code Update as follows

```
@if (show)
{
    <div>...</div>
}
@code
{
    bool show = false;
    public async Task GeneratePdf()
    {
        show = true;
        StringBuilder ABS_string = new StringBuilder();
        string html_1 = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("BlazorUniversity.outerHTML", ABSTitle);
        string html_2 = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("BlazorUniversity.outerHTML", ABSHU);
        ABS_string.Append(html_1);
        ABS_string.Append(html_2);
        string html = ABS_string.ToString();
        show = false;
    }
}
```